# two-value bitmap,white is 1,black is 0 in java?

Tags: java, bitmap, digital

I use class `PixelGrabber` to get a two-value bitmap's pixel array.  But one problem comes out, a two-value image(white or black), I stored these pixels of the bitmap in a int array, these elements of the array shouldn't be 1(white) or 0(black) but in my code I find white is -1 and black is -16777216.  Anyone know why?

Now I would like to just simply use a `for` loop to change -1 and -16777216 to 1 and 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using the `PixelGrabber(ImageProducer ip, int x, int y, int w, int h, int[] pix, int off, int scansize)` constructor, in which case what you're getting back is an integer array of the RGB value of each pixel.

Because it's coming back as an RGB value - you need to seperate out the values to give you a true RGB value. For example RGB(255,255,255) is White and RGB(0,0,0) is black. The [API Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/PixelGrabber.html) gives a good example of how to do this properly. With the `-16777216` number in your question, I performed a simple test which shows that it is actually black:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int pixel = -16777216;

        int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;
        int red   = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
        int green = (pixel >>  8) & 0xff;
        int blue  = (pixel      ) & 0xff;

        System.out.println(alpha);
        System.out.println(red);
        System.out.println(green);
        System.out.println(blue);


    }
}
```

> Prints out: 255, 0, 0, 0

Follow the API reference linked above for example code of how to handle the pixel data correctly.

Comment: hi,great,I know it now.thank you.I indeed used constuctor PixelGrabber(ImageProducer ip, int x, int y, int w, int h, int[] pix, int off, int scansize).and I know where i was wrong now .I thought the int array stored index of RGB palette in bitmap format,ok,it's wrong,int array store the RGB data directly even though the image is two-value image if I get pixels through the class PixelGrabber.oh,so if I use Class Image to get a picture,no mater what's format it is ,it will be a "java image object",no mater hold the bottom picture format-filehead ,infohead, RGB palette,image data?